# populating a drop down list from 2 columns from database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a table user in my database containing 2 columns first name and last name.
I want to populate a drop down list so the user can choose from the drop down list a person according to his first and last name.

So how can i enter first and last name into one drop down list?

This my drop down list so far.

```
<telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="DepIDVoit" 
   HeaderText="Voiture" UniqueName="IdVoiture4"
   ListTextField="VMarque"  DropDownControlType="DropDownList" 
   ListValueField="VVID" FilterControlAltText="Filter VMarque column"  
   ShowFilterIcon="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" 
   AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
    <ColumnValidationSettings 
           EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true"  >
      <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" 
           ErrorMessage="* Mandatory Field">
      </RequiredFieldValidator>  
    </ColumnValidationSettings>
 </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
```

I want to put in the ListTextField : VMarque and VModel separeted with a space

Comment: "First Name" + " " + "Last Name"

Comment: it throws an error, because it takes that as literal content

Comment: only other way that I can think of is thru some 3rd party controls but am not sure how helpful those would be for you as they are, for the most part WinForms. such as: http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/MultiColumnComboBoxControl.aspx or

Comment: @MikeMouannes you are to do the concat in your SQL query as a new column. of course replace "first name" "last name" with the actual column names

Comment: i found a solution and it works, it so simple, all i had to do is that in my sql query i should hav joind the 2 field as shown bellow for Vmarque and Vmodel

    SELECT ID as VVID,   Marque + ' - ' + Model as VMarque FROM Voiture WHERE (Voiture.IdUtilisateur = @idUser) "

Comment: yeah exactly as u said but i just saw ur answer thanks anyways :)